# Not able to click on checkbox using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I tried to use `objectIdentifierValue`

```
id - cntMain_chkPrimaryInvestigator_A   
name - ctl00$cntMain$chkPrimaryInvestigator_A    
xpath - //input[@id='cntMain_chkPrimaryInvestigator_A'] 
xpath - //span/div/input
```

but none are working,I am getting errors like "No such element found on web page".

```
Going through the examples given for all the other related questions I could not find a proper solution that works in a concise way that allows me to check a checkbox with a few lines of code or method.
```

How we can select such checkbox using a webdriver script?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the below html code :

```
<div class="input-heading nonresearchHide">
    <span id="cntMain_lbl_Primary_investigator">Primary investigator</span>
    </div>
    <div class="nonresearchHide">
    <div class="icon-info" data-content='Please add the Primary Investigator that was responsible for the research if they are not already added to this activity' data-placement="top" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-trigger="hover"></div>
    <p class="defaultP">
    <div class="RadAjaxPanel" id="ctl00_ctl00_cntMain_chkPrimaryInvestigator_APanel">
    <span class="check_box">
    <input id="cntMain_chkPrimaryInvestigator_A" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$cntMain$chkPrimaryInvestigator_A" tabindex="7" />
    </span>
    </div>
    </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should be adding more details, like your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='check_box]")).click();
```

Try with clicking on span which is parent of that particular input

Comment: I tried with above xpath but it is also not working. There has been some jquery is getting invoked in the background. Is there any way to handle jquery in selenium

Answer (score 0):

have u tried this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("cntMain_chkPrimaryInvestigator_A")).click();
```

if this does not help, pls show details of your code.

Comment: I have already tried driver.findElement(By.id("cntMain_chkPrimaryInvestigator_A")).click();
My Code is as below : 
element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(objectIdentifierValue)));
element.click();     
element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(objectIdentifierValue)));
element.click();
     
I tried with following objectIdentifierValue as  
->id=cntMain_chkPrimaryInvestigator_A  
->name=ctl00$cntMain$chkPrimaryInvestigator_A
->xpath=//input[@id='cntMain_chkPrimaryInvestigator_A']
->xpath=//span/div/input